# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que un contador aumente dependiendo de la cantidad que ingrese el usuario en los campos utlizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, condiciones, botón

¡Hola! Tenía pensado hacer una pequeña función en jQuery para poder indicarle a un usuario la cantidad de galletas que puede hacer dependiendo de la cantidad de ingredientes que haya ingresado en los respectivos campos.

Los datos que utilizo para poder preparar *una* galleta son 200 gramos de azúcar, 100 gramos de harina, una cucharada (16 mililitros) de aceite y una taza (250 mililitros) de agua. Obviamente, si el usuario ingresa una cantidad mayor a eso quería especificarle cuantas galletas podría llegar a hacer. El tema es que no sabría ¿cómo poder aplicarle un contador para que vaya aumentando dichas cantidades de galletas que puede hacer dependiendo de los ingredientes que tenga disponibles?

Les puedo dejar algo de lo básico de JavaScript y jQuery abajo:

```
$("#btnCalcular").click(calcularRecetas);

let azucar;
let harina;
let aceite;
let agua;
let galleta = 0;
// una galleta = 200g azúcar && 100g harina && 16ml aceite && 250ml agua //
let cantidadGalletas =0;

function calcularRecetas(){
    galleta++;
    azucar = Number($("#txtAzucar").val());
    harina = Number($("#txtHarina").val());
    aceite = Number($("#txtAceite").val());
    agua = Number($("#txtAgua").val());
    if(azucar>=200 && harina>=100 && aceite>=16 && agua>=250){
        // cantidadGalletas = cantidadGalletas + 1//
    }
}
```

También les dejo la estructura básica del documento HTML para que pueda ingresar dichos datos:

```
<body>
    <label for="txtAzucar">Ingresar cantidad de azúcar (g):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAzucar"><br><br>
    <label for="txtHarina">Ingresar cantidad de harina en gramos (g):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtHarina"><br><br>
    <label for="txtAceite">Ingresar cantidad de aceite en (mL):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAceite"><br><br>
    <label for="txtAgua">Ingresar cantidad de agua en (ml):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAgua">
    <input type="button" value="Calcular Recetas" id="btnCalcular">
    <p id="pTotal"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Tendrias que usar un ciclo for e ir disminuyendo las cantidades de azucar, harina, aceite y agua que vayas consumiendo, es decir, cada vez que entres al if, sumarle uno a la galleta  y restarle a tus variables la cantidad minima que se necesita de ese ingrediente para hacer una galleta, con eso tendras la cantidad de galletas que puedes hacer, de hecho dentro de la funcion no deberias poner que se sume de una una galleta... que tal si enrealidad la persona nisiquiera tiene ingredientes suficientes para hacer una galleta?

Comment: Ademas siempre sumas una galleta dentro de la función calcularRecetas si o sí... por lo que te dara resultados incorrectos a no ser de que luego la resetees en alguna parte o solo añadas galletas dentro de tu condición de ingredientes.

Comment: Es mas, es mejor para este caso un ciclo while, mientras que aún haya suficiente de cada uno de los ingredientes para hacer una galleta, seguir iterando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no es necesario que te compliques con un ciclo, solo necesitas saber con cada ingrediente la cantidad mínima de galletas que podrías hacer, por ejemplo, si de azúcar, aceite, agua tienes suficiente para hacer 10 galletas, pero de harina solo para hacer 1, pues solo podras hacer 1, es decir, tu determinante siempre sera el minimo, te recomiendo usar división entera y calcular el mínimo de tus variables, seria algo asi:

```js
w = 400; //azucar
x = 200; //harina
y = 32; //aceite
z = 500; //agua

azucar = Math.floor(w/200);
harina = Math.floor(x/100);
aceite = Math.floor(y/16);
agua = Math.floor(z/250);

minimo = azucar;

if(harina<minimo)
{
  minimo = harina;
}
else if(aceite<minimo)
{
  minimo = aceite;
}
if(agua<minimo)
{
  minimo = agua;
}

console.log(minimo);
```

Comment: cuidado, estas comparando harina con azucar al inicio, luego comparando aceite con harina, luego comparando agua con aceite, no es correcto y fallará con otros valores.

Comment: Hmmmm de hecho estas imprimiendo el mínimo de estos pero no necesariamente la cantidad de galletas que hay.

Comment: w =700, x = 500, y = 32, z = 100

Comment: No pero enserio, no es por ser mala onda ni para que lo tomes a mal, lo siento si depronto suenan agresivos o te ofendieron mis comentarios, de verdad que no lo hago con esa intención, lo hago es por que hay que tenerlo en cuenta, no podemos pasarlo por alto si solo va a funcionar en ciertas ocasiones, con el fin de ambos aprender, me excuso contigo Josue sin embargo me parece bastante buena tu forma de verlo es excelente ya que puede que haya una forma de hacerlo así como tu dices usando 3 o 4 if, excelente.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.onload = ()=>{

    $("#btnCalcular").click(calcularRecetas);

    let azucar;
    let harina;
    let aceite;
    let agua;
    let galleta = 0;
    let cantidadGalletas = 0;
    // una galleta = 200g azúcar && 100g harina && 16ml aceite && 250ml agua //
    
    const minimoIngredientes = {
        azucar: 200,
        harina: 100,
        aceite: 16,
        agua: 250
    }

    function calcularRecetas(){

        let galletas = 0;

        azucar =  Number($("#txtAzucar").val());
        harina =  Number($("#txtHarina").val());
        aceite =  Number($("#txtAceite").val());
        agua   =  Number($("#txtAgua").val());

        while(
            (azucar > 0 && harina > 0 && aceite > 0 && agua > 0) &&
            (azucar >= minimoIngredientes.azucar && harina >= minimoIngredientes.harina && 
             aceite >= minimoIngredientes.aceite && agua   >= minimoIngredientes.agua)
        ){
            azucar -= minimoIngredientes.azucar;
            harina -= minimoIngredientes.harina;
            aceite -= minimoIngredientes.aceite;
            agua   -= minimoIngredientes.agua;
            galletas++;
        }

        cantidadGalletas = galletas;
        console.log(cantidadGalletas);
    }
    

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="txtAzucar">Ingresar cantidad de azúcar (g):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAzucar"><br><br>
    <label for="txtHarina">Ingresar cantidad de harina en gramos (g):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtHarina"><br><br>
    <label for="txtAceite">Ingresar cantidad de aceite en (mL):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAceite"><br><br>
    <label for="txtAgua">Ingresar cantidad de agua en (ml):</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtAgua">
    <input type="button" value="Calcular Recetas" id="btnCalcular">
    <p id="pTotal"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Checa el código, lo unico que hice fue:

quitar esta línea:

```
galleta++;
```

en la función calcular recetas, tambien inclui un objeto en donde almacenar el minimo numero de ingredientes que se requiere por ingrediente:

```
const minimoIngredientes = {
        azucar: 200,
        harina: 100,
        aceite: 16,
        agua: 250
}
```

Tambien en la función calcular recetas, añadí la variable local `galletas`:

```
let galletas = 0;
```

Y por ultimo, en la función calcular recetas en vez de usar un if, use un ciclo while para crear un ciclo que solo va a parar de acuerdo a la siguiente condición:

```
while(
    (azucar > 0 && harina > 0 && aceite > 0 && agua > 0) &&
    (azucar >= minimoIngredientes.azucar && harina >= minimoIngredientes.harina && 
        aceite >= minimoIngredientes.aceite && agua   >= minimoIngredientes.agua)
){
    azucar -= minimoIngredientes.azucar;
    harina -= minimoIngredientes.harina;
    aceite -= minimoIngredientes.aceite;
    agua   -= minimoIngredientes.agua;
    galletas++;
}
```

Mientras que todos los ingredientes sean mayor a cero, es decir, que tenga ingredientes y mientras que haya como minimo la cantidad necesaria para crear otra galleta el ciclo se va a ejecutar, y dentro nos aseguramos de restar los ingredientes usados, de lo contrario caeriamos en un ciclo infinito, y ademas al entrar aquí significa que se puede hacer una galleta, por lo cuál la sumamos al contador:

```
azucar -= minimoIngredientes.azucar;
harina -= minimoIngredientes.harina;
aceite -= minimoIngredientes.aceite;
agua   -= minimoIngredientes.agua;
galletas++;
```

Por ultimo asignamos a `cantidadGalletas`, la cantidad de galletas calculadas por el ciclo:

```
cantidadGalletas = galletas;
```